# Jenkins-CI mail configuartion concern

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to trigger the jenkins build creation process by sending mail to any dummy Id or with any external system we can trigger the build creation process like CLI or any other?

Actually the main problem is that earlier we in our system use the perforce as a repository and we have the build generation system which creates the build once we mailed to dummy Id created by us now we are switching to Continuous Integration so is that possible with Jenkins that we trigger the build creation process by sending the mail to particular Id or any dummy Id, I have googled this very much but doesn't find any good suggestion, if it is possible please explain............

Answer (score 0):

jenkins has api to start a build. can make own email reader with javax.mail jsut few lines so if there is new mail trigger cli.